# Javascript history back not working with document location

Tags: javascript

I've been using this inline js for the odd button to navigate backwards.

```
href="javascript:history.back()"
```

However, I've also got a function that does this:

```
function DelayTarget(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var t = $(e.target);

    var href = ((t.is("a") ? t : t.find("a")).first()).attr("href");

    if (typeof href !== typeof undefined && href !== false) {

        setTimeout(function () { document.location = href; }, 600);
    }
}
```

The function also workd in its own right, and redirects after a short delay.

However, when i use the two together - I click on a delayed link then try to navigate back, the page is not in browser history. I recently changed the code to use document.location believing that this would work.

Not being a JS expert, I'm struggling to come up with alternative code that might work.

Comment: My if loop is being reached. The redirect takes place, but it's not recorded in the browsers history.

Comment: Which page is not in the history? The one you are on before you click the link or the one you want to go to with `history.back`?

Comment: If you're going "back", the 'current' page won't be in the history but in the "future".

Comment: It's the one I'm one before the click. I click the button, click my own back button, but there's no navigation back.

Comment: I think I know whats happening, but I don't know why, or how to fix it. The back button is calling the same delay function, so in theory, it should delay then go back. But in this case the href isn't an href - its a piece of javascript.

Comment: I'm getting somewhere, I now know how to redirct the history back but this  href="javascript:history.back()" is returning undefined in the code above. ???

Comment: Fixed under a different question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505769/jquery-returns-undefined-for-href-when-not-a-proper-href

Comment: Comment surplus - answer above