# jquery returns undefined for href when not a proper href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function DelayTarget(e) {

    var t = $(e.target);

    var href = ((t.is("a") ? t : t.find("a")).first()).attr("href");

    if (typeof href !== typeof undefined && href !== false) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

When I test with this link it works correctly:

```
href="/contact"
```

When I test with this link it doesn't work:

```
href="javascript:history.back()"
```

The first test correctly identifies the href value but the second returns undefined. It seems odd that jquery would know the difference between a valid and invalid url.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

UPDATE - this is what is causing the issue:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a>
```

Comment: Works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x126fy1p/ Which browser are you testing with? Have you checked the console for errors? What does your HTML and click handler look like?

Comment: Firefox 40 - no console errors.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome either

Comment: There must be a wider issue then, as you can see from the fiddle that the example code you've posted is correct.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - thanks for the feedback. I'm using Google's material icon font stack (see the update in the main post) - if I include it, it fails. ????

Comment: in fact - its the <i></i> tag

Comment: Because the target is what you click....`console.log(e.target)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp):

> The `target` property gets the element on which the event originally occurred, opposed to the `currentTarget` property, which always refers to the element whose event listener triggered the event.

So it fails because `e.target` returns the innermost DOM element clicked, in this case the `<i>`. It has nothing to do with the fact that one of the links contains JavaScript. To solve the problem, just change `e.target` to `e.currentTarget`.

Alternatively, use `this` instead:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    DelayTarget(this);
});

function DelayTarget(o) {
    var t = $(o);
    var href = (t.is("a") ? t : t.find("a")).first().attr("href");
    if (typeof href !== typeof undefined && href !== false) {
        // Do something
    } 
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s8c2nk1/3/).

Comment: Perfect anders - you learn something new every day. Better check the rest of my code now!